# Passing data from a view to a different views controller in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a form displayed for editing values already saved to a database. One of the values is an image (in the form of a relative file path). I want to create a link within the form to display the image in a separate view when clicked.

My question is what is the best way to pass this view's (edit view) image field data to the controller of the view that will display the image independently?

I would rather not do it via the url.

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to do it via the url, in the view you show it in, you could require a login. Also, you could show the image inline with the form, or maybe when they on a link to view the image, you could pop up the image in a modal window or something.

Comment: All good suggestions. Thanks! All options are summed within this comment and the accepted answer below. Show content on current page, pass id of content via url or post a form with desired db content to the external view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the ID of the record you're editing. Then in your controller, you'd have a function like view_image($id) which fetches the images relative path from the database, based on the $id field passed in.

Then you can display the image however you want in the view_image.ctp view file.

UPDATE:

First and formeost, the question is why don't you want to include the ID in the URL? Sometimes people feel insecure about showing ID's publicly, but in most cases, there's no problem with it at all.

Anyway, assuming you have a legitimate need not to include the ID in the URL, the other way to do it would be to pass the id (or the image path for that matter) in via POST, rather than in the URL (GET). You know the difference? GET includes the parameters in the URL, where as POST wraps them up in the request itself, so they're not in the URL.

If you want an example of doing this, CakePHP does it in the case of it's default Delete functions and links that get generated by the Bake console.

In the case of deleting a record, here's an example of a POST link in the view:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $product['Product']['id']),array('class'=>'delete'), __('Are you sure you want to delete %s?', $product['Product']['list_title']));
```

And the example controller method looks like this:

```
public function admin_delete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $this->Product->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Product->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid product'));
    }
    if ($this->Product->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Product deleted'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Product was not deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

So you shouldn't find it too hard to adapt that for your own purposes.

Comment: But you are passing the id via url right? via $this->Html->link() ? Is there a way to do it without passing via url?

Comment: Store the URL in the a session variable and use that inside the other view?

Comment: I wouldn't involve sessions, that's probably overkill. I've updated my answer with more info. Basically, use the postLink method of Cake's Form helper - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink

Comment: $this->Form->postLink is just what I needed. Thanks!